# finding good hash function for languages accepted by finite state automata

Tags: hash, hashcode, regular-language, state-machine, formal-languages

I'm working on project in Java (but I think it doesn't depend on the language) where I'm generating small (4 states max) nondeterministic finite state automata on binary alphabet and I have to check fast the generated automaton for equivalence with the previous ones. Therefore, I have to use some good hash function, to avoid compairing with too many automatas.

My first thought was doing a DFS on the transitions and finding all the accepted words until length max. 5 and then I map the set of accepted words to a 64-bit long (the amount of binary words of length max. 5). But it seems to produce too many collisions on NFAs with 4 states. Increasing the length results in making the computing of the hash code too slow for practical use.

Another approach was having a set of words and testing which of them the automaton accepts but finding the right ones, I think, isn't that trivial.

Do you have any idea how to improve the hash function to avoid too many collisions without a significant loss of speed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use the subset construction to turn the NFAs into DFAs, then minimize the DFAs into canonical DFAs?

Comment: yes, it's possible. The detrminisation is quite a cheap operation. Now I use Brozowski algorithm for dfa minimisation, which seems to be quite slow, but I hope Hopcroft will be faster - I will implement it. Do you think it will help with computing the hash somehow?

Comment: @RafaelK.: You can use the minimized DFA as the hash, by comparing exactly the states and transitions

Comment: Why use a hash or minimization?  You can compare two DFAs directly by using the distinguishable-pairs matrix as discussed in Hopcroft&Motwani&Ullman Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation (3rd ed, Addison-Wesley 2007) Section 4.4.1.  You'll need to construct the matrix anyway for minimization, but you don't have to go any further to compare automata for equivalence.

Comment: @ibid: yes, but I'm generating billions of them - I need to minimize the number of comparisons with the previous ones. Therefore I need some good hash function or something, that would exclude as many non-equivalent automata as possible.

Comment: Okay.  In that case I'd try first minimizing each DFA, assigning names for the states in the minimal DFA using some deterministic method that produces the same assignment for every structurally equivalent DFA and then computing a simple deterministic string representation of the DFA's transition table, including information about final states.  Those strings you can then hash or compare like any string.

I don't make this an answer because I have no idea if it's good enough for your use case :)

(Looks like your own answer is basically the same idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking further (thanks @justhalf and @templatetypedef) and I have an idea - an injective function of any NFA (or more precisely, language accepted by it) to integers - Let's have an NFA A. Let's construct minimal DFA A_min accepting the same language with complete delta-function. As a consequence of Myhill-Nerode theorem, this automaton should be unambiguous except isomorphism. Do a BFS from the initial state giving priority to the edges(transitions) based on some fixed order of characters in the alphabet (for example first 0, second 1). And renumber the states based on the order of visiting. Now we have a canonical minimal DFA and we can map the incidence matrix of states to an integer and append enumeration of final states (or better make a tuple, to avoid collision). This integer could be then used for deciding equivalence of two NFAs. Do you think, it is ok or have any other idea?

Comment: if this works, the advantage should be, that hashing and mutually comparing some long integers is way more simple and efficient than hashing and testing for equivalence directly automata.

Comment: If your NFAs have at most 4 states, then the DFAs have at most 2^4 = 16.  You'll need 48 bits (three for each state) to represent the state transition table and the final state table.  That fits into a modern 64-bit processor's register quite nicely.  Not so long integers, that means.

Comment: I don't understand, how you need only 3 bits for every state when encoding transitions. My calculations are, if I have a DFA with 16 states, that I need for every state 4 bits to encode the number of state to go on 0, 4 bits to encode the number of state to go on 1, that means 8 bits for every state (128 bits in total), which fits into two 64-bit integers. And for encoding the list of final states I need 16 bits - which fits into one short int.